# Add new nodes to a set of existing nodes (Perl XML::LibXML)

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

Using the Perl XML::LibXML library, I'm trying to add a new node to each of a set of existing nodes in an XML document, using a loop.  This is my attempt so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.14.2;
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "xml_doc.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$parser->keep_blanks(0);
my $dom = $parser->parse_file($filename);

for my $node ($dom->findnodes("/poem/stanza/v"))
{
    my $elm = $dom->createElement('newnode');
    $elm->appendText('This is a new node');
    $_->addChild($elm);
}

say $dom->toString(1);
```

File 'xml_doc.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<poem>
<stanza>
<v>As I was going to Bonner,</v>
<v>Upon my word of honor,</v>
<v>I met a pig</v>
<v>Without a wig,</v>
<v>As I was going to Bonner.</v>
</stanza>
</poem>
```

The program fails with the error 'Can't call method "addChild" on an undefined value at batch_add_nodes.pl line 16.'

Any tips would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make up your mind whether your `for` loop iterator variable is `$node` or `$_` :-)

If I replace `$_->addChild($elm)` with `$node->addChild($elm)` your code works and gives this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<poem>
  <stanza>
    <v>As I was going to Bonner,<newnode>This is a new node</newnode></v>
    <v>Upon my word of honor,<newnode>This is a new node</newnode></v>
    <v>I met a pig<newnode>This is a new node</newnode></v>
    <v>Without a wig,<newnode>This is a new node</newnode></v>
    <v>As I was going to Bonner.<newnode>This is a new node</newnode></v>
  </stanza>
</poem>
```

Comment: Many thanks Dave for spotting that bug.  I was closer to the solution than I thought.